# How to combine .with() and .resize() in one script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you help me with the following?
I have this working javascript code.
This code makes the bootstrap columns in a row all an equal height for screens with a bigger width than 640px.

```
if($(window).width() >= 640){
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".row").each(function () {
    var highestBox = 0;
    $(".col", this).each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > highestBox) highestBox = $(this).height();
    });
    $(".col", this).height(highestBox);
  });
});
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is that if I resize the window from less than 640px to more than 640px, I have to refresh the page in order to see the changes.  I'd like a script that automatically checks the window size. I think the .resize() function can help me with this but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Could you eventually accept an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 3):

You could implement it as follows. Put your code inside a function, let's call it `resizeMe()` .Then:

```
var rtime,
    timeout = false,
    waitingTime = 200,
    resizeFinished = function () {
        if (new Date() - rtime < waitingTime) {
            window.setTimeout(resizeFinished, waitingTime);
        } else {
            timeout = false;
            if ($(window).width() >= 640) {
                resizeMe();
            }
        }
    };

    $(window).resize(function () {
        rtime = new Date();
        if (timeout === false) {
            timeout = true;
            window.setTimeout(resizeFinished, waitingTime);
        }
    }).resize();
```

With this function, your function `resizeMe()` is fired *only* when the resizing process has finished. That way it is assured that `resizeMe()`isn't fired at every mouse move but only if `waitingTime` is reached (200ms). This is quite important for performance. (Thanks to urban pointing at)

Comment: This also preserves CPU on some browsers that fire the `resize` event too often while the mouse is mouving

Answer (score 2):

You could use following snippet, using [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) ([support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) **&** [polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)) method and binding handler in `load/resize` window events:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(this.resizeTimeout);
  this.resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 640px)").matches) {
      $(".row").each(function() {
        var highestBox = Math.max.apply(null, $(this).find('.box').map(function() {
          return this.clientHeight; // or $(this).height()
        }));
        $(this).find('.box').height(highestBox);
      });
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

**EDIT** Adding debouncing regarding good point done in [@Daenu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35100575/1414562)

Answer (score 1):

just make a function and pass it to window

```
function resizeMe(){
 if($(window).width() >= 640){
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".row").each(function () {
   var highestBox = 0;
   $(".col", this).each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() > highestBox) highestBox = $(this).height();
  });
   $(".col", this).height(highestBox);
   });
 });
 }
}
```

then attach an event to window and pass your function

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeMe);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the

```
$(document).ready(function () on the top before the if($(window).width() >= 640)
```

you can use

```
 $( window ).resize(function() function
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Daenu's answer. A compressed/simplified version that is reusing the same timeout:

```
$(function(){
    timeout = null
    waitingTime = 200


    $(window).resize(function(){
        // Clear old timeout
        if (timeout)
            clearTimeout(timeout)
        // Set new
        timeout = setTimeout(resizeMe, waitingTime);
    })
})

function resizeMe(){
    $(".row").each(function () {
        var highestBox = 0;
        $(".col", this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).height() > highestBox) highestBox = $(this).height();
        });
        $(".col", this).height(highestBox);
    });
}
```

The idea is that if resize is fired while there is an active `timeout`, we cancel the old and re-schedule a new one

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hq1jd47v/2/